# Passing updating listbox to other form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

As the title, i know that many people asked this kind of questions. I have read manys, i success in passing the items in listbox to other form, but in case listbox is adding many new items, i don't know how.
The listbox only update when i reopen the form. This is my code. My way to open new form is modified the Program.cs cuz the listbox is non-static

.....

```
static class Program
    {
        private static Lm f1;      //This is my Main form
        private static Form1 f2;   // This is the second

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            f1 = new Lm();
            f1.VisibleChanged += OnLmChanged;

            Application.Run(f1);
        }
       static void OnLmChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                if (!f1.Visible)
                {
                    f2 = new Form1(f1.listBox2, f1.listBox3, f1.label7);
                    f2.Show();
                    f2.FormClosing += OnFormChanged;
                }

            }
            static void OnFormChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                    f1.Show();

            }
```

My code on the second form (Form1)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(ListBox listBox, ListBox list1, Label ll)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox2.Items.AddRange(listBox.Items);
            //listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, args) =>    //This didn't work
            //{
                //listBox2.Refresh();
                //listBox2.Items.AddRange(listBox.Items);
            //};
    }
```

I realize that i shouldn't put the "listBox2.Items.AddRange" in public Form1(..) but i don't know how.. :(
(listBox2 is updating in Lm Form, i'm trying to passing it to Form1 Form)

Comment: your listbox is filled with a collection of data, pass the collection/list not the listbox itself

Answer (score 0):

What does "in public Form1" mean? Do you mean the constructor? The constructor is actually a very good place for initialization. In fact, that's exactly what they were invented for. You've put that code where it belongs, but you can and should improve the way it's written.

What's not so good is passing a listbox to the constructor as a parameter, when all the constructor wants is a collection of items. Maybe the collection you're providing *this time* happens to belong to a listbox, but that's not important. The same goes for the label text: All Form1 really wants is some text. It doesn't care if the text came from a label somewhere. So have it ask for just the text.

So just pass the items:

```
public Form1(System.Collections.IEnumerable items, 
             System.Collections.IEnumerable otherItems, 
             String labelText)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listBox2.Items.AddRange(items);

    //  etc.
}
```

And call it like so

```
static void OnLmChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (!f1.Visible)
    {
        f2 = new Form1(f1.listBox2.Items, f1.listBox3.Items, f1.label7.Text);
        f2.Show();
        f2.FormClosing += OnFormChanged;
    }

}
```

It would be good to give `listBoxItems` and `otherListboxItems` much more specific and descriptive names, but you've provided no information about what the listboxes mean. `listBox1` and `listBox2` communicate nothing about what's in the listboxes or what purpose they serve in the user interface. That's very bad programming practice. A year from now if you come back to fix this code, you will not know at a glance what this is doing:

```
listBox2.Items.AddRange(items);
listBox3.Items.AddRange(otherItems);
```

This, however, actually tells you something:

```
recipeListBox.Items.AddRange(recipes);
ingredientListBox.Items.AddRange(ingredients);
```

Maybe it's cars or animals or zipcodes instead of recipes. The same principle applies. It would be easy to get `items` and `otherItems` mixed up as to which is which. It's much harder to mix up `recipes` and `ingredients`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm kind of new with C# so i'm just totaly forget about naming things :( 
I'm trying your suggestion and it's worked ok. But when ListBox in Main Form only has 1 item and value of this item keep changing, listbox in second form won't update until i reopen it =.=

Comment: @MinhLee Passing the listbox itself to the Form1 constructor will not fix that problem. If you need to notify Form1 of ongoing changes in Form2, you need an event. I'm not eager to try to answer your new question, because if your question has completely changed once, it will probably keep changing every time I try to answer it. Can you provide a complete, final version of the question that you really want to ask?